# Cant install UBUNTU 13.10 on my laptop

Tags: installation, boot

I have HP 430 Series Notebook With Windows 7, I have downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 ISO and tried to install along side windows 7, So i booted from DVD, but after choosing all options of installation my lap restarted and the DVD Tray got opened automatically and got a black blank screen, so i tried all again and now i got some test on same blank screen asking me to remove all installation media and hit Enter. i did that and i normally booted to Windows 7. What could be that problem

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, it could be a lot of things.
It might even be a bug in the installer or a DVD with errors.

I persume you did not try to run Ubuntu directly from DVD ?
It might be a smart move to test that first.

If that fails, try to use another ISO (even another Ubuntu version, like 12.04 LTS) burn it at slow speed on a CD and try to run it and eventually install it.
If it works you can check the 13.10 DVD for errors.